# Google Guava isNullOrEmpty for collections

Tags: java, guava

I see that Guava has isNullOrEmpty utility method for Strings

```
Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str)
```

Do we have anything similar for Lists? Something like

```
Lists.isNullOrEmpty(list)
```

which should be equivalent to

```
list == null || list.isEmpty()
```

Also, do we have anything similar for Arrays? Something like

```
Arrays.isNullOrEmpty(arr)
```

which should be equivalent to

```
arr == null || arr.length == 0
```

Answer (score 151):

No, this method does not exist in Guava and is in fact in our "idea graveyard."

We don't believe that "is null or empty" is a question you ever really want to be asking about a collection.

If a collection might be null, and null should be treated the same as empty, then get all that ambiguity out of the way up front, like this:

```
Set<Foo> foos = NaughtyClass.getFoos();
if (foos == null) {
  foos = ImmutableSet.of();
}
```

or like this (if you prefer):

```
Set<Foo> foos = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(
    NaughtyClass.getFoos(), ImmutableSet.<Foo>of());
```

After that, you can just use `.isEmpty()` like normal.  Do this immediately upon calling the naughty API and you've put the weirdness behind you, instead of letting it continue on indefinitely.

And if the "null which really means empty collection" is not being returned to you, but passed to you, your job is easy: just let a `NullPointerException` be thrown, and make that caller shape up.

Comment: What if some framework is setting it field to null and you can't control it (spring framework when on binding to list) although you explicitly set and use empty list in the object.

Comment: My answer is the same: try to remove the ambiguity by normalizing `null` to an empty collection as soon as you can. If you just can't, then okay, you might be one of the <1% of users who really want to write their own trivial isNullOrEmpty(Collection) helper.

Comment: (or skip the helper and just write `if (collection == null || collection.isEmpty())` in those cases where you need it! Is that so bad?)

Comment: This is an opinionated answer that doesn't actually address the question at all. It also goes against defensive programming principles.

Comment: @Neovibrant since the question is about the capabilities of the Guava library, and the answer is from one of the lead developer of Guava, the answer is kinda implied: "No, Guava doesn't have that". The answer may be improved by starting with that statement though :)

Comment: So you should start to believe that it is sometimes useful to ask this question. My proposal is to write some validator which is considering if there is any element in collection for some external data. Writing code like you've proposed will be just ridiculous in validators like this.

Comment: @Grundlefleck okay, did that.

Comment: It'd be awesome if Guava added a Lists.nullToEmpty() method for consistency.

Comment: ironic because Google's own Drive SDK's love to return null in place of empty collections, whenever it can... I was dealing with this fact when I searched for a Guava `isNullOrEmpty` for collections

Comment: Also, couldn't the exact same argument be made for null Strings? Why create Strings.isNullOrEmpty() but not Collections. equivalent?

Comment: I think "isNotEmpty" would be useful for readability because in "!sdadsifai.dsaoifh().adsfoish().isEmpty()" the negation symbol and isEmpty() are visually so far apart it makes the code easy to misunderstand.

Comment: @user2986984 - the problem is there's no positive synonym to 'non empty'.  Personally I've grown to like the word 'laden', but that's hardly common.

Comment: How is normalizing null to an empty collection different from normalizing a null String to an empty String? I second @DonCheadle

Answer (score 37):

One thing you will tend to find throughout Guava is that they tend to be very antagonistic toward `null`s. The authors want to discourage you from using `null` as much as you probably do, and providing utility methods to make it easier to use `null` would be counterproductive against this end.

If you want to use Guava's paradigm, consider if the source of this collection (or array) really ought to optionally return `null`. If not, consider marking it `@NonNull` and return empty collections instead of `null`. Or as a parameter to a function that is expecting no `null`-valued lists, consider using `Preconditions.checkNotNull`, which throws an exception if a `null` is (unexpectedly) passed in.

If `null` really is legitimate, `list == null || list.isEmpty()` is not that hard.

Comment: it's inconsistent. The same argument could be made for Strings, yet there *is* a Strings.isNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 33):

There's a [CollectionUtils.isEmpty()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty(java.util.Collection)) in commons-collections.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to have been removed in more recent versions.  See org.apache.commons.collections15.CollectionUtils.

Comment: Looking at the Javadoc from apache.commons.collection the methods isEmpty() and isNotEmpty() still exist in the latest version. collections15.CollectionUtils seems like an independent project trying to provide generic support.

Comment: CollectionUtils.isEmpty() is useful when working with legacy apps, when you cannot change the up front code.

Comment: we know this, but one was asking about guava not about apache commons.

Answer (score 11):

Spring Framework has specialized util class called `CollectionUtils`. And the method you are looking for is: `org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.isEmpty`. It returns true for null and empty collections.

And for arrays there is `org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.isEmpty` method which behaves pretty the same.

Comment: Although it's probably safe to use it, this class is marked with "Mainly for internal use within the framework" comment. This means its interface might change on a Spring upgrade and you will have to do additional work to make it work again.

Answer (score 3):

Apache CollectionUtils 4 has a method [CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#emptyIfNull%28java.util.Collection%29) that returns a empty list if the collection is null.  This is very useful in a foreach loop, so you dont need to do a null check before iterating

Answer (score 1):

My solution is : MoreObjects.firstNonNull(list, Collections. emptyList())

I am using Guava MoreObjects with JDK Collections.

```
 @Test
public void listnull() {
List<String> list = null;

for (String str : MoreObjects.firstNonNull(list, Collections.<String> emptyList())) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("http://stackoverflow.com/");

for (String str : MoreObjects.firstNonNull(list, Collections.<String> emptyList())) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what's suggested in the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6921270/113632), except you don't use an `ImmutableList`.

Comment: I think negative because one wanted simple & quick solution like apache commons methods inNotEmpty ...

Comment: Help Center > Privileges > Vote Down When should I vote down?
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Do you think my answer is "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"? If not, why are you negative voting?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Appache Collections
CollectionUtils.isEmpty()
returns true if collection is null or empty