# Is there a JDK or Guava method to turn a null into an empty list?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Is there a method like this one in the JDK or Google Guava

```
public static <T> Collection<T> safe(Collection<T> collection) {
    if (collection == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>(0);
    } else {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

which makes it easy to not crash on a an enhanced loop if something returns a null list for example

```
for (String string : CollectionUtils.safe(foo.canReturnANullListOfStrings())) {
    // do something
}
```

would not crash.

I looked around but could not find any such method, and I am wondering if I missed it or if there is a reason why such a handy method is not handy and therefore not included?

Comment: Methods should not return `null` collections in the first place.

Comment: I believe such a method can be easily written using `Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: @SLaks agreed in principle but you can't control other peoples code :)

Comment: One somewhat confusing way to protect yourself from code that returns `null` instead of an empty `Collection` is to use AspectJ and after-advice. Create a pointcut that matches execution of methods returning `Collection`, and return an empty `Collection` if the original return value is `null`. Repeat for `Map`, `List`, etc. Your colleagues may not appreciate this, however.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Objects.firstNonNull(list, ImmutableList.<Foo>of());
```

There's no need for a specialized method, and this [is indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921270/869736) the solution we recommend you use immediately whenever you get a potentially-null collection from a naughty API that ideally shouldn't do that in the first place.

Comment: What a way to make simple task look complicated. Use apache collections ListUtils.emptyIfNull from comment below. reads way better.

Comment: This is exactly why people make fun of Java. There are far more readable solutions given by others.

Answer (score 28):

Apache Collections 4 has a generic method `ListUtils.emptyIfNull(List<T> list)`

Here is the doc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html

Comment: Best non-java 8 solution.

Answer (score 18):

In Java 8 it is possible to use this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(foo.canReturnANullListOfStrings()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Answer (score 7):

Update for Java 9:

`java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse(collection, List.<T>of())`

The `<T>` is still required.

Answer (score 1):

So there does not exist a function to my knowledge of this sort.  However writing one is trivial as you have shown above.  The reasoning behind why it might not have been included is because `null` has a specific meaning and it might not be appropriate to return an empty `Collection` when one gets passed around.  Generally (in my experience) when a null value enters the system something failed higher up the chain or an invalid value was not properly sanitized.

Comment: Unfortunately I see it quite often in a generated wrapping e.g. some JSON. And construction like `for(String thing : someObjFromJson.getFoo().getBar().getListOfThings()) {...do stuff...}` becomes not trivial without such method.