# is there isEmpty in Guava?

Tags: java, apache, guava

Is there any equivalent in google Guava for [apache commons' `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.util.Collection%29) to check if a collection is null or empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if `Collection` is **both** null and empty, you must do null check by yourself. Guava devs advocate not to use `null`s for `Collection`s at all - see [IdeaGraveyard](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#Iterables.isNullOrEmpty) on Guava Wiki:

> Prefer to return empty collections instead of null. Then a plain isEmpty check will suffice.

EDIT:

See this [SO answer by Guava's lead dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910002/google-guava-isnullorempty-for-collections/6921270#6921270).