# Normalising ugly method parameters using Guava

Tags: java, guava

I have a class which contains an optional `Map`:

```
 private Optional<ImmutableMap<String, String>> stuff;
```

In my class constructor I am passed `Map<String, String> inputStuff`, where `inputStuff` could be:

- `null`
- an empty `Map`
- a populated `Map`

For the first two instances I need to store `Optional.absent()` and for the third instance I need to store an `Optional` immutable copy of the map.  The best that I can come up with in terms of handling this is:

```
    final ImmutableMap<String, String> tmp = ImmutableMap.copyOf(Objects.firstNonNull(inputStuff, ImmutableMap.<String, String>of()));
    if (inputStuff.isEmpty())
    {
      this.stuff = Optional.absent();
    }
    else
    {
      this.stuff = Optional.of(inputStuff);
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Optional` or `null` here at all, rather than just using the empty map to represent the empty map?

Comment: It's for consistency with other bits of the code, where there is a difference between an absent map and an empty map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just simply do:

```
if (inputStuff == null || inputStuff.isEmpty()) {
  this.stuff = Optional.absent();
} else {
  this.stuff = Optional.of(ImmutableMap.copyOf(inputStuff));
}
```

I don't see a reason why should you create a temporary variable here. If you prefer using ternary operator, you can even avoid duplicated assigment to `this.stuff`.

Comment: Yeah reason the code looks like it did is that I was hoping for some additional method that could be used to simply convert `tmp` to `absent`, somewhat similar to `Strings.emptyToNull()`, and so avoid the multi-line initialisation.  Given that there isn't anything like that out there I'll mark this answer as correct.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: [`Iterables.isNullOrEmpty`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#Iterables.isNullOrEmpty) was explicitely rejected by Guava team, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910002/google-guava-isnullorempty-for-collections/6921270#6921270).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this:

```
this.stuff = (inputStuff == null || inputStuff.isEmpty()) 
   ? Optional.absent()
   : Optional.of(ImmutableMap.copyOf(inputStuff));
```

Or the way @Xaerxess posted it. It's much more straight-forward and easier to guess what's going on here.